# When use redirect in htaccess, it redirect to another page

Tags: .htaccess

i have some problem with htaccess redirect

i have this code,
`RewriteRule ^details/(.*)$ schemas.php?item=$1 [L,QSA] RewriteRule ^details/(.*)/(.*)$ uzelOpen.php?item=$1&schema=$2 [L,QSA]`
when url is exmp: 'http://127.0.0.1/details/some/else', he redirect to schemas.php, but i need to uzelOpen.php

UPD: Why u dislike my problem, i need help guys :((

2UPD: ok, i found an answer a reversed the positions of theese rows